# Get Correct Elasticsearch Document Returned if Matches Query Terms and Is Newest Document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get a search to return the newest document only if it matches any of the terms being queried.

Consider the following documents:

```
submitterId:635535 action:CREATE billerId:009207 marketBase:RH submitterDisabled:N versionDate:20190818141059
submitterId:635535 action:UPDATE billerId:009207 marketBase:RH submitterDisabled:N versionDate:20190827170044
submitterId:635535 action:UPDATE billerId:009207 marketBase:RH submitterDisabled:Y versionDate:20190827174522
```

What I want is for a user to search on any of the elements (minus versionDate) and only find the newest document in a group.  The added caveat is that if they search for a value that does not match anything in the newest document, it should return nothing.

Example:
Search for "submitterDisabled=N".  Considering the example docs above, nothing should be returned because the newest record does not contain a matching value.  It has "submitterDisabled="Y".

Unfortunately, the way we have our query setup, it is doing a straight match on the term before doing any sort of aggregation on the versionDate.  I know that's the issue, but don't know how to approach a fix.  Warning, I'm extremely new to ES.

Does anyone have an idea on what may be going on here?

```
GET _search
{
    "size":0,
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {
                    "term":{"submitterId.keyword":"635535"}
                },
                {
                    "wildcard":{"marketBase.keyword":"*"}
                },
                {
                    "term":{"submitterDisabled.keyword":"N"}
                }]
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "group":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"submitterId.keyword",
                "size":10000
            },
            "aggs":{
                "group":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"marketBase.keyword"
                    },
                    "aggs":{
                        "group_docs":{
                            "top_hits":{
                                "size":1,
                                "sort":{
                                    "versionDate.keyword":{"order":"desc"}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your query just a little.

First, since you always want to get the elements with the `"submitterDisabled.keyword":"Y"`, you can just set it in your query and no matter what your users select, you will always return the ones with that value equal to "Y".

Now, for the part that your docs only need to match with one field's value, you can add a `should` condition.

`must`works as an AND, while `should` works as an OR. So setting a should condition in your query will return only the docs that match with at least one of those values.

Finally, you just have to mix what I said before and your query will be something like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {
                    "term":{"submitterDisabled.keyword":"Y"}
                }
            ],
            "should":[
                    {
                        "term":{"submitterId.keyword":"635535"}
                    },
                    {
                        "wildcard":{"marketBase.keyword":"*"}
                    }
                ]
        }       
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: Additional, if you don't want to show the results with "submitterDisabled.keyword":"N", you can do two things: 1. Don't let your users to select the option or 2. If they select that option, don't do the query at all and return an empty dict.